# Reveal image on canvas with draw/strokes/paint

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to achive the following:

1. Draw a bg-image to the canvas (once or if needed repeatedly)
2. The image should not be visible at the beginning
3. While i "paint" shapes to the canvas the bg-image should get visible where the shapes were drawn

The parts of the image that will be revealed shall be "painted" (like with a brush) so i want to use strokes.

What i tried:
- Do not clear the canvas
- Paint rects to the canvas with globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'
This works, the rectangles reveal the image but i need strokes

If i use strokes they are ignored with 'destination-in' while i see them with normal globalCompositeOperation.

Is this intended that the strokes are ignored? Is there a workaround like somehow converting the stroke/shape to a bitmap? Or do i have have to use two canvas elements?

In OpenGL i would first draw the image with its rgb values and with a = 0 and then only "paint" the alpha in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve it by these steps:

- Set the image as a pattern
- Set the pattern as `fillStyle` or `strokeStyle`

When you now fill/stroke your shapes the image will be revealed. Just make sure the initial image fits the area you want to reveal.

Example showing the principle, you should be able to adopt this to your needs:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image,
    radius = 40;

img.onload = setup;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/bnAEEXq.jpg";

function setup() {
  
  // set image as pattern for fillStyle
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
  
  // for demo only, reveals image while mousing over canvas
  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var r = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left,
        y = e.clientY - r.top;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=900 height=600></canvas>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Trees and Forest. That could be a solution. Now if i would like to improve the drawstrokes with, lets say a shadow for smooth edges i would end with the same problems i guess - for example if i would want to combine image draws and shape draws. Could you share a thought on that? I guess i have to use two canvases then?

Comment: @Alex hmm, yeah.. you would need to build the stroke in one canvas with smoothing using solid color etc. Then use a comp mode and draw the image over which will use the alpha information in the stroke, and finally transfer the result to main canvas. The solution shown here won't do for that am I afraid (I made the solution based on the subject though :) ).

Comment: I realize this post is from 8 years ago, but I came across it just now and am wondering, is there a way to calculate how much of the space has been revealed by the user. For example after 80% of image revealed, hide the canvas (reveal the rest of the image.) let me know if anyone sees this and has an answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution:

1. Put the image as a normal image on your website
2. add a canvas and use CSS positioning to place it right above the image
3. Fill the canvas with the color you use as the page background
4. have your paint tools erase the canvas when you draw. By the way, you can set `context.globalCompositionOperation = 'destination-out'` to turn all drawing operations into an eraser.

Here is an example. As you can see, the alpha properties of your tools are respected.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//prepare canvas
ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 120, 120);

//prepare a 30% opacity eraser
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';

// make random strokes around cursor while mouse moves
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
   var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
   var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
   var y = e.clientY - rect.top;

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(x + Math.random() * 33 - 16, y + Math.random() * 33 - 16);
   ctx.lineTo(x + Math.random() * 33 - 16, y + Math.random() * 33 - 16);
   ctx.stroke();

}
```

```html
<span>Move your mouse:</span>
<div>
<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/120px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png' style='position:absolute'>
<canvas id='canvas' width=120 height=120 style='position:absolute'></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have written in my question that the result should respect the alpha of the painted strokes. This is needed because this shall result in a pencil stroke for example and should be tintable. So actually the same/related problem to a tinted bitmap-fill.

Comment: @Alex when you use globalCompositionOperation = 'destination-out', alpha should get respected.

Comment: @Alex I made you an example. As you can see, alpha is supported.

Comment: Thanks for hurting my wrist.

Comment: what is the point of the * 33 -16?

Comment: @louisebelcher To create a random number in the range between +16 and -16.